# geo algorithm in the Redis

Tags: math, redis, geometry, geospatial, geohashing

I check the geo source code of Redis, and one statement I cannot understanding is `double difference_longitude = asin(sin(distance) / cos(latr));`
What's the  `asin(sin(distance) / cos(latr))` meaning? Is there any theory from the wikipedia?

http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/deps/geohash-int/geohash_helper.c

```
#define D_R (M_PI / 180.0)

static inline double deg_rad(double ang) { return ang * D_R; }
static inline double rad_deg(double ang) { return ang / D_R; }

int geohashBoundingBox(double longitude, double latitude, double radius_meters,
                       double *bounds) {
    if (!bounds) return 0;

    double lonr, latr;

    lonr = deg_rad(longitude);
    latr = deg_rad(latitude);

    if (radius_meters > EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
        radius_meters = EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS;
    double distance = radius_meters / EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS;
    double min_latitude = latr - distance;
    double max_latitude = latr + distance;

    /* Note: we're being lazy and not accounting for coordinates near poles */
    double min_longitude, max_longitude;
    **double difference_longitude = asin(sin(distance) / cos(latr));**
    min_longitude = lonr - difference_longitude;
    max_longitude = lonr + difference_longitude;

    bounds[0] = rad_deg(min_longitude);
    bounds[1] = rad_deg(min_latitude);
    bounds[2] = rad_deg(max_longitude);
    bounds[3] = rad_deg(max_latitude);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It tells you that a meter on the equator corresponds to a smaller longitude difference than a meter close to the north pole.

Comment: @LutzL, Yes you are right, however why we use  "asin(sin(distance) / cos(latr));"? why not used other formula, you know there are should be any formula can that meaning,  is there any theory behind it or any wiki article can describe this formula?

Comment: `distance` refers to a path on the sphere, thus an angle relative to the center of the sphere. The sine is then the length of the secant, i.e., straight line segment. `cos(latr)` is the radius of the latitude circle, the quotient thus the sine of the angle on the latitude circle.

Comment: @ LutzL, thank you for your help.

Comment: @ LutzL,BTW , can you kindly help to check my another related Queu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461221/whats-the-difference-between-area-and-boundingbox-from-rediss-source-code ?